# my route do not work ,use express and ejs

Tags: javascript, express, web, routes, ejs

i want to click link to solution page,but my route don't work,what's wrong?

1. app.js

   ```
   var express = require('express'); var path = require('path'); var
   favicon = require('serve-favicon'); var logger=require('morgan');
   var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); var bodyParser =
   require('body-parser'); var expressLayouts =
   require('express-ejs-layouts');

   var index = require('./routes/index'); var users =
   require('./routes/users');

   var app = express();

   app.set('layout', 'layout/layout'); app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

   app.use(expressLayouts);
   app.use(logger('dev')); app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   app.use(cookieParser()); app.use(express.static(path.joindirname,
   'public')));

   app.use('/', index); app.use('/users', users); app.use('/solution',
   index);
   ```

   2.routes/index
       var express = require('express');
       var router = express.Router();

   ```
   router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('pages/index'});
   });

   router.get('/solution', function(req, res) {
        res.render('pages/solution');
   });

   module.exports = router;
   ```

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting and can you put your ejs file?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok,thanks for your remind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use this code

```
var express = require('express'); 
var path = require('path'); 
var favicon = require('serve-favicon'); 
var logger=require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');

var router = express.Router(); // need to add 
var index = require('./routes/index')(router); /* need to pass router object */
var users = require('./routes/users')(router);  /* need to pass router object */

var app = express();

app.set('layout', 'layout/layout'); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(logger('dev')); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser()); 
app.use(express.static(path.joindirname,'public')));

app.use('/', index); 
app.use('/users', users);
```

In ./routes/index file update the following code

```
module.exports = function (router) { 

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
         res.render('pages/index'});
    });

    router.get('/solution', function(req, res) {
         res.render('pages/solution');
    });

};
```